# Need to delete specific rows that are missing an email

Tags: openoffice, open

I have a spreadsheet I want to delete the rows that are missing an email.  How do I sort and delete each of those rows?

Answer (score 1):

If you require to maintain the current listing order, a simple, nearly brute-force method follows below:

- Create an additional column in the sheet, fill with ordinal numbers
  (1, 2, 3, etc).
- Perform an alphabetic data sort on the entire spreadsheet, using    the email
  column as the reference.
- This will move all the blank rows    to the top, allowing you to
  manually select and delete them
- Perform a    data sort on the entire spreadsheet using the ordinal
  column as the    reference
- This will return the sheet to the original configuration.
- Manually delete the ordinal column.

There may be more sophisticated methods using scripts/macros/etc, but sometimes simple works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do! A simple sort will work. 
I will assume that a single row will contain all the information for a particular entity. I will also assume that you always use the same column for email addresses. With those assumptions in place, do the following:

Highlight the entire area (all rows and columns) that contains the data you wish to clean. Right click on the highlighted area, point at Sort> and click on Custom Sort.

If your columns have headers that you can use, make sure to check the header box. Choose the column that contains the email addresses as the sort field and click the OK button.

This should bring the rows that have blanks in that field to the top. Just highlight and delete those rows.